# É possível armazenar em variáveis o resultado de um ANALYZE TABLE ou SHOW no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Boa noite, pessoal, tudo bem?

Estou com uma dúvida um pouco boba referente ao retorno dos comandos `ANALYZE TABLE` e `SHOW` no MySQL.

Eu sei que se eu fizer uma consulta utilizando `SELECT` poderei armazenar os valores desejados em variáveis de duas maneiras (até onde eu sei), que seria essa:

`SET @Name= SELECT Name FROM users WHERE Id = 1;`

Ou essa:

`SELECT Name INTO @Name FROM users WHERE Id = 1;`

Particularmente prefiro a segunda maneira, pois poderia preencher mais de uma variável com uma única consulta, mas minha dúvida não é sobre o `SELECT` e suas formas de armazenar resultados de consulta em variáveis, e sim de como armazenar os valores que um `ANALYZE TABLE` ou que um `SHOW` retornam.

Se eu executar, por exemplo, o comando `ANALYZE TABLE users` em um `schema` chamado teste, terei esse resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E eu gostaria de armazenar o `Msg_text` em uma variável por exemplo, talvez para utilizar em algum algoritmo que envie um e-mail de alerta, ou algo parecido.

Acredito que, se houver como armazenar o resultado de um `ANALYZE TABLE` em variável, seria de uma maneira semelhante para armazenar o resultado de um `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE`, ou algum outro `SHOW`, apesar de que percebi que a maioria das informações que esse comando retorna estão armazenados na base `information_schema`, mas acabei ficando curioso se teria como armazenar o retorno desse comando também.

Comment: O que você precisa certamente é possível, mas eu recomendaria dar uma lida na documentação das funções para ver se ela realmente está agindo de acordo com a suas expectativas. O `ANALYZE TABLE`, por exemplo, limpa os dados estatísticos da tabela em análise, [segundo a documentação (último parágrafo)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html).